# How can I make the segment line with increase on hover?

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like the segments to change line width on hover. I am trying to modify the hover glyph of the renderer but it is set to `None`.

Minimal example 1:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, save

p = figure()
r = p.segment(x0=[1,2], y0=[2,3], x1=[10,20], y1=[20,30],line_width=3)
r.hover_glyph.line_width = 6

output_file("hover.html")
save(p)
```

Gives the error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'line_width'

EDIT:
I am using bokeh 1.3.4

Minimal example 2:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, save

p = figure()
r = p.segment(x0=[1,2], y0=[2,3], x1=[10,20], y1=[20,30], line_width=3, hover_line_width=6)

output_file("hover.html")
save(p)
```

Gives the error:

> AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'hover_line_width' to Segment, similar attributes are line_width

Minimal example 3:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, save
from bokeh.models import Segment

p = figure()
r = p.segment(x0=[1,2], y0=[2,3], x1=[10,20], y1=[20,30], line_width=3)
r.hover_glyph = Segment(x0=[1,2], y0=[2,3], x1=[10,20], y1=[20,30], line_width=6)

output_file("hover.html")
save(p)
```

Gives the error:

> ValueError: expected an element of either String, Dict(Enum('expr', 'field', 'value', 'transform'), Either(String, Instance(Transform), Instance(Expression), Float)) or Float, got [1, 2]

EDIT2:
Minimal Example 4 works:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, save
from bokeh.models import Segment, HoverTool

p = figure()

r = p.segment(x0=[1,2], y0=[2,3], x1=[10,20], y1=[20,30], line_width=3)
p.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers=[r]))
r.hover_glyph = Segment(line_width=6)

output_file("hover.html")
save(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using hover glyphs adds overhead, so Bokeh does not create them automatically, unless asked for one. You are trying to set a property on a hover glyph that does not exist. You can either:

- set the convenience parameter values to `segment`:

  ```
  p.segment(..., hover_line_width=6)
  ```

  Bokeh will pick up on this request, and create the hover glyph for you
- set a hover glyph explicitly yourself using the low level `Segment` model:

  ```
  r.hover_glyph = Segment(..., line_width=6)
  ```

There is information and examples of both these techniques [in the docs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#glyphs).

Comment: I have seen the docs. Have you tried the code? It doesn't work for me, see my edit above.

Comment: You can't pass literal data lists/arrays to low level glyph objects. They can only be configured to use columns from a ColumnDataSource. All the low level examples demonstrate this. If the hover parameter is not working then it's a quirk of segment, which lacks the fill properties most glyphs have. (AFAIK you are the first person to ever try hover on segments) A GitHub issue would be appropriate.

Comment: And for that matter if you look at the examples in the docs I linked you can see they pass no data or column names to the low level glyph objects, like you are trying to do. The ancillary glyphs like hover or selection, etc are only used to specify the visual properties that should be used in those situations. They always use the same data as the main glyph.

Comment: right, I missed that! I have used glyphs so many times and never without a source so calling glyphs without data is totally new to me. And now if I actually add the Hover tool it works, see example 4 above. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it's working! Please make a GH issue about the parameter not working, that would be good to fix at some point.